# database table not updating in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview, rows

I have the following code to Update the database from dataGridView after the user inserts the text:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 0159";

        // Prepare a string where you insert parameter's placeholders instead of
        // concatenating the grid values....
        string Query = @"Update TopShineDB.table1 set CarColorNumber = @CarColorNumber, Interior = @Interior, 
                 Exterior = @Exterior , CPlastic = @CPlastic, MPlastic = @MPlastic, SPlastic = @SPlastic, 
                 PlasticB = @PlasticB, WashExt = @WashExt, WashEng = @WashEng, WashTrunk = @WashTrunk, 
                 WashSeats = @WashSeats, SeatsRmv = @SeatsRmv, SeatsFit = @SeatsFit, Notes = @Notes  
                 where `Time` = @Time";

        // Using statement around connection and command to destroy
        // these objects at the end of the using block               
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // Create the list of parameters required by the query
            // Notice that you should use the appropriate MySqlDbType
            // for the field receiving the value.
            command.Parameters.Add("@Time", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@CarColorNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Interior", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Exterior", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@CPlastic", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@MPlastic", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@SPlastic", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@PlasticB", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@WashExt", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@WashEng", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@WashTrunk", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@WashSeats", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@SeatsRmv", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@SeatsFit", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Notes", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

    try
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    // Inside the loop update the parameters' values
                    // with data extracted by the current row...
                    command.Parameters["@Time"].Value = dr.Cells[0].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@CarColorNumber"].Value = dr.Cells[1].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@Interior"].Value = dr.Cells[2].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@Exterior"].Value = dr.Cells[3].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@CPlastic"].Value = dr.Cells[4].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@MPlastic"].Value = dr.Cells[5].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@SPlastic"].Value = dr.Cells[6].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@PlasticB"].Value = dr.Cells[7].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@WashExt"].Value = dr.Cells[8].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@WashEng"].Value = dr.Cells[9].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@WashTrunk"].Value = dr.Cells[10].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@WashSeats"].Value = dr.Cells[11].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@SeatsRmv"].Value = dr.Cells[12].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@SeatsFit"].Value = dr.Cells[13].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@Notes"].Value = dr.Cells[14].Value;

            // ExecuteNonQuery for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, 
            // ExecuteReader works but it is specific for reading
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get no errors in the application and everything runs fine, but when I check the table I realize that nothing changed in the rows. why is it not updating?

Comment: You are updating where a time field is equal to a time parameter. Time is exceedingly difficult to get exact equality on. Are you sure the parameter being passed in is equal to a record in your table? How is your table defined, and can you give a sample of the data in your table?

Comment: yeah because its actually an entry to tell when this car arrived. so yeah the user specifies the time

Comment: If you debug the code and get the values from your executing code parameters and execute the query manually, does it work?

Comment: well, I did use the same code before for Insert query and it worked. but for some reason its not working on the Update query.

Comment: Insert is completely different, it is not reliant on a `where` clause. You are likely not getting the correct value you are expecting for the comparison on the update.

Comment: I agree, it is different. but what is stressing me is that i'm not getting any errors. so I don't have a clue what's happening.

Comment: You should extract the query from your code during debug and run it manually to see what exactly is being passed as parameters and what exactly is being executed.

Comment: Also try replacing `'time'` with `[time]`

Comment: I got a syntax error

Comment: Try to spit final sql statement 
string query = command.CommandText;

foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
{
    query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
}

Debug.WriteLine(query); 

Take the output of the query and test it directly.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? Ping people with an @ in front of their name with no space. Otherwise they move on, forget about you, and never get informed

Comment: Change your code a bit to know if any record updated. int recs=command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. But I spent hours working on this and i ended up using 2 queries. I used delete and then inset. I know it's not the best solution but then it works.